# Upgrade the Hadoop version from 2.6.0.3 to 2.6.3

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

[image]we have hadoop cluster with HDP version - 2.6.0.3

our target is to upgrade the version from 2.6.0.3 to 2.6.3 ( 2.6.3 is the last certified version )

this upgrade can be done by Ambari GUI and by clicking the relevant TAB's

but we want full upgrade automation by CLI or REST API

**is it possible? , and if yes can we get info about this Rest API ?**

Comment: Just `yum install ambari-server` (or apt-get). You can't upgrade the OS packages from a REST API

Comment: sorry , I update the question , we mean the hadoop version not the ambari version  , you right ambari can installed by yum , but not the hadoop , so any option to install the hadoop version by API instead from the ambari GUI?

Comment: There is no hadoop version **2.6.0.3**... Hadoop has always had 3 digits. http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html  You can seem to be confused what you're asking for, but still Ambari doesn't do OS package upgrades over REST

Comment: @cricket_007 see my update in the question and see the HDP version - 2.6.0.3 , this was from ambari GUI

Comment: HDP does not mean "Hadoop" it means "Hortonworks Data Platform"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused that Hortonworks HDP, Ambari, and Hadoop all maintain individual versions.

HDP has maintained Hadoop 2.7.3 for quite some time.

Ambari 2.6.x would be installed by your OS package manager, and you need to stop both the server and the agents in order to upgrade it. Therefore, there will be no REST calls being made. With that version of Ambari, you can upgrade the HDP stack definitions (maybe via REST), but you'll still need to trigger an upgrade and rolling restart action. And the latest HDP is actually 2.6.4, and I'm not sure I understand what a "certified version" is, but I imagine it's no different than "generally available, released" version.

The entire upgrade process is outlined in the [HDP Upgrade documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.1.3/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/ambari_upgrade_guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are python and groovy `ambari-client` implementations at Ambari repo, but as of 2.6.x, they don't support dealing with upgrades.
You may record REST API requests from browser (e.g. using `Postman` interceptor) and replay them from your script, or use Selenium. Sequences of API requests for upgrade may have slight differences between Ambari versions.

REST API reference is https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md (choose appropriate branch name, e.g. `branch-2.6` in url).

Comment: +1 for the info about Postman interceptor and  https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md